# Simple SQL query: Retrieve a value depending on a date?

Tags: sql, filemaker

I'm hitting a wall. Need help building a very simple SQL query. It's a tiny table "USt", that looks like this:

```
id Datum Steuersatz Steuersatz%
1 1983-07-01 2 .07
2 1998-04-01 1 .16
3 2007-01-01 1 .19
```

It contains tax rates (Steuersatz%) that stay in effect until another tax rate supersedes it. So, it can be extended at any time with maybe:

```
4 2015-01-01 2 .09
```

I have the date (Datum) and the Steuersatz (values 1 or 2). Now, the question is, what are the correct Steuersatz% values?

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT \"Steuersatz%\" FROM USt
WHERE Steuersatz = 1
AND …
```

I need this for an `ExecuteSQL()` statement within FileMaker, where only some basic SQL syntax is supported.

Example results:

```
.16 <= Steuersatz = 1 , Date = 2006-12-31
.07 <= Steuersatz = 2 , Date = 2006-12-31
.07 <= Steuersatz = 2 , Date = 2014-12-31
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a Correlated Subquery (I hope it's supported in FileMaker)

```
select Steuersatz% 
from USt
where Steuersatz = 1
and Datum = (select max(Datum)
             from USt
             where Steuersatz = 1
               and Datum <= your_date)
```

Comment: Yes! That's the solution. Thank you very much.

In case anyone is interested, this is how the FileMaker function looks like:

`Let ( [ _sts = 1 ;`
`  _d = Date ( 12 ; 31 ; 2014 ) ;`
`  _query = "`
`  SELECT \"Steuersatz%\" FROM USt`
`  WHERE Steuersatz = ?`
`  AND Datum = ( SELECT MAX(Datum)`
`     FROM USt`
`     WHERE Steuersatz = ?`
`     AND Datum <= ?`
`     )`
`  " ;`
`  _% = ExecuteSQL ( _query ; "" ; "" ; _sts ; _sts ; _d ) ;`
` ] ;`
` _%`
`)`

Comment: YES!  That did the job. Thank you very much! See below the FileMaker version.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it looks like as a FileMaker function:

```
Let ( [ _sts = 1 ;
        _d = Date ( 12 ; 31 ; 2014 ) ;
        _query = "
        SELECT \"Steuersatz%\" FROM USt
        WHERE Steuersatz = ?
        AND Datum = (   SELECT MAX(Datum)
                    FROM USt
                    WHERE Steuersatz = ?
                    AND Datum <= ?
                    )
        " ;
        _% = ExecuteSQL ( _query ; "" ; "" ; _sts ; _sts ; _d ) ;
    ] ;
    _%
)
```

Comment: Ooops, there is one semicolon too much at the end: ` _d ) ;`